# Add nullable decimals in C#

Tags: c#, nullable

Let me reformulate. I am inside a ForEach loop what is supposed to add calculated decimal? values to the decimal? originalAmount that is of course null on the first time as you pointed out.
So I just need to check null first otherwise do the addition.

```
decimal? convertedAmount = Calculate(inputValue); //always returns a value

originalAmount = originalAmount==null ? convertedAmount : originalAmount + convertedAmount;
```

The originalAmount is defined earlier, outside the loop.

Sorry for the confusion, the question can be closed / deleted if necessary.

Comment: "does not work" is very vague. Please specify what you've observed vs what you expected.

Comment: You can't use `+=` since the variable `originalAmount` does not yet have a value. Consider the simpler: `int i = 2; int j += i;` Now: what is `j`? why?

Comment: I only want the originalAmount to have a value if the convertedAmount has, otherwise it should be null.

Comment: How "does not work" ? What you are suggesting is legal in the language syntax. You need to at least state what you expect and what the actual results are.

Comment: Did you want `decimal? originalAmount = convertedAmount;`?

Comment: @akrobet - What you want to do makes no sense.  Why don't you just check to see if `originalAmount` is null and if it is set it equal to `convertedAmount` otherwise add `convertedAmount` to the current value of `originalAmount`

Comment: @MarcGravell, please write your observation as answer so we can close thsi question.

Comment: sorry for the vague question, I found it out in the meantime from the suggested replies:

originalAmount = originalAmount==null ? convertedAmount : originalAmount + convertedAmount;

Comment: Have you really tried above code? It throwing error on my side.

Answer (score 6):

(from comments)

> I only want the originalAmount to have a value if the convertedAmount has, otherwise it should be null.

So:

```
decimal? convertedAmount = ...

decimal? originalAmount = convertedAmount;
```

which does everything in that requirement.

You *could* be more verbose, but **this serves no purpose**:

```
// unnecessary: don't do this:
decimal? originalAmount =
    convertedAmount.HasValue ? convertedAmount.Value : (decimal?)null;
```

Comment: Sorry, forgot to mention in the question that I am inside a loop, and I need to ADD the convertedAmount to the originalAmount.

Answer (score 3):

You need to specify how your addition should behave when one or both values are null. As a suggestion try something like this:

```
decimal? convertedAmount = ...
decimal? originalAmount = ...
if (convertedAmount.HasValue)
{
    originalAmount = originalAmount.GetValueOrDefault() + convertedAmount.Value;
}
```

Comment: @Andrew: Sorry, you're wrong. Nullable<T>.GetValueOrDefault() will return the default value of T if the nullable does not have a value. T is decimal here, which is a value type and cannot be null itself. So, it will never return null, but (decimal)0 here.

Comment: Oops you are right! It returns: "The value of the Value property if the HasValue property is true; otherwise, the default value of the underlying type." https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.nullable-1.getvalueordefault?view=netframework-4.8